# Having trouble with a function that has to split a string into roman numbers weights

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, roman-numerals

i wrote this code:

```
admitted_List = [1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000]
tempString = ""
finalList = []
for i in range(len(xkcd)-1):
    if int(xkcd[i] + xkcd[i+1]) in admitted_List:
        tempString += xkcd[i]
        continue
    else:
        tempString += xkcd[i]
        finalList.append(int(tempString))
        tempString = ""
return (finalList)
```

that basically takes in (xkcd) a string of weights of roman numbers like '10010010010100511' and it should return me the list of weights like [100, 100, 100, 10, 100, 5, 1, 1] so that C C C XC V I I makes sense, of course the first 4 chars of the string make the number 1001 that in roman numbers means nothing so my number will be 100 and then the check should stop and begin a new number.

I tried the above algorithm.
Please excuse me if bad code or bad body question, I'm pretty new to python and stack overflow.

Comment: Will you provide code that shows how `xkcd` is initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Set the list of numbers from higher to lower value

The idea for this snippet of code is to list the decimal numbers corresponding to roman numbers from bigger value to lower value (see the new definition of variable `admitted_List`).

Your code become the following:

```
def func(xkcd):    
    admitted_List = ["1000", "500", "100", "50", "10", "5", "1"]
    tempString = ""
    finalList = []
    loop_out = 0
    while loop_out == 0:
        for roman_num in admitted_List:
            #print(roman_num)
            if (xkcd.startswith(roman_num)):
                finalList.append(int(roman_num))
                xkcd = xkcd[len(roman_num):]
                if len(xkcd) == 0:
                    loop_out = 1
                break
    return (finalList)

xkcd = '10010010010100511'

print(func(xkcd))
```

It prints the following list: [100, 100, 100, 10, 100, 5, 1, 1]

Comment: Thank you, it was precious.

Answer (score 1):

No need to go extra complex with functions! How about using `re.split()` combined with list comprehension?

```
text = '10010010010100505011'

[i+j for i,j in zip(re.split('(1|5)',text)[1::2],re.split('(1|5)',text)[::2][1:])]
```

Returns:

```
['100', '100', '100', '10', '100', '50', '50', '1', '1']
```

We can then either map them to roman, or transform to `int` by using `int(i+j)` in the solution proposed above.

Comment: This works but it is too advanced for me, thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Try to split it function by function, you might want to follow approach rather than chaining multiple variables, while and for loops. It might be complex at first, but I strongly suggest you take your time!